# fixture_file_upload gives a "{***} has an extension that does not match its contents" from paperclip model rails 4.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, paperclip

I'm having this issue with uploading paperclip documents with rails fixture_file_upload (after upgrading rails version)

Knowing that paperclip 4.0 and above requires validating content_type, My specs still fails with the error: `File has an extension that does not match its contents` even after either after the validation or specifically requesting `do_not_validate_attachment_file_type`.

I'm having this scenario in multiple(all my) paperclip models...

An example is as follow:

Model:

```
class SignatureFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_attached_file :file
  VALID_CONTENT_TYPES = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

  validates_attachment :file, content_type: { content_type: VALID_CONTENT_TYPES },
                              convert_options: { all: '-auto-orient' },
                              processors: [:compression]
  ...
end
```

Spec:

```
image = fixture_file_upload('spec/fixtures/mobile_api/sample.jpg', 'image/jpg')
```

When I try to save `image` above, it fails, and `image.errors.full_messages` gives:

> "File has an extension that does not match its contents"

Suffice to say I have a bunch of scenarios like this one which was previously passing before the upgrade.

Below are versions of the related gems I have:

- gem 'rails', '4.2.7.1'
- gem 'paperclip', '4.2.1'
- gem 'paperclip-compression', '0.3.7'
- gem 'rspec-rails', '3.4.2'

What can I be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing `file`, sadly the error isn't more precise in those cases. Read in the [paperclip docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#file).

Comment: On Windows you'll have to add ` :binary` to the fixture_file_upload.  https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/TestProcess/fixture_file_upload